# string templates are not supported by current javascript version

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use [ES6 String Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in a Node.js (v 5.7.0) [app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/1-hello-world), but they are not working. Webstorm is correctly warning me that

> String templates are not supported by current Javascript version

I am sure I have used string templates in a node app in the past. How can I get string templates to work? I am running the server with this command

> npm start

When that is fixed, how can I help Webstorm know it is fixed and stop showing the warning?

**Edit:**
I changed the [app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/1-hello-world) source to use template strings in this manner:

`````

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`App listening at http://${host}:${port}`);
```

`````

the app prints:

> App listening at http://:::8080

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you try in the REPL? It works for me.

[image]

If the code doesn't throw an error it means that the template strings works. But if the result is not what you expected, just console.log your variables to see what's inside.

**Edit:** Concerning the WebStorm warning, [it seems pretty easy to fix](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/).

Comment: Yes. I get the same results as you.

Comment: Does you code works or is ut just the WebStorm warning bothering you? If so, just tell WS you're using ES6 (see my edit).

Comment: Ok, how does it "not work"?  Does it throw an error? Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: I updated my question to show the code and the result.

Comment: So the `${port}` works (right?) and the `${host}` is replaced by `::`? Can you `console.log` it?

Comment: I just realized only ${host} is not printing as expected. This is probably more a problem understanding Node than es6 template strings.

Comment: console.log(host) results in ::

Comment: I was fooled by the result + the warning from Webstorm. I was expecting "localhost" to be printed.

Comment: I see. Did you fix the warning issue with my link? And try to log `server.address()`, to find out all the informations you can get. Finally, don't hesitate to validate the answer if you find it (or the comments)  helpful!

Comment: I'd like to accept, but I think the correct answer would explain that "::" is expected.

Answer (score 20):

String templates are supported in JavaScript version ECMAScript 6 and above.

To fix this in **Web Storm**:

Webstorm IDE

-> File

-> Settings

-> Languages & Frameworks

-> JavaScript

-> Javascript Language Version:

Choose **ECMAScript 6** instead of **ECMAScript 5.1** or any older version.